# Create XSD to ignore HTML within tags

Tags: html, xml, ssis, xsd

Is it possible to build an XSD that will treat any tag's contents just as text? I am trying to extract a tag's contents that sometimes contains HTML tags. There is no fixed pattern to the html and is not always present. I just want to extract all the text from within the tags. `e.g. <content>this is a new piece of content by <b>Person A</b></content>.` I want to extract just `"this is a new piece of content by <b>Person A</b>"` but the schema generated by SSIS naturally includes these tags. When I just add a simple entry

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="content" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
```

I get the following error which is not unexpected.

> [XML Source [5]] Error: The XML Source was unable to process the XML
>   data. The element "content" cannot contain a child element. Content
>   model is text only.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the XSD primarily as describing allowed markup in a valid XML document rather than as a method to define extraction.  If you change the type of `content` to `xs:string`, you're declaring that markup is not permitted within `content`, only text, and the validation error you're getting reflects that.

What you want is to select the ***string value*** of the `content` element.  If the context for an XPath doesn't automatically convert its results to a string value, you can do so explicitly via the `string()` XPath function:

```
string(/path/to/particular/content)
```

This will return the concatenation of the string values of all of the children of `content`, omitting the tags as requested.

**Update**: Re-reading your question, I see that you actually want to retrieve

```
"this is a new piece of content by <b>Person A</b>"
```

(including the `b` element, not its string value).  Here, the wrapping `content` element clearly has to be described in the XSD as having mixed content (`mixed="true"`).  Extracting this data from an XML document in this form would typically involve selecting a collection of text and elements nodes, and serializing these back to a single string.  I am not familiar enough with SSIS to provide details, but perhaps the reference I mentioned in the comments could help.

Comment: thanks very much. I did try as you suggested. ``<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="content" type="xs:string">
    <xs:selector xpath="string(/content)"/>
  </xs:element>``      This gave an error on the SSIS - selector element not supported
</xs:schema>

Comment: You need to learn how to use XPath in SSIS.  See [Using the XML Task to Run an XPath Query](http://agilebi.com/jwelch/2008/07/23/using-the-xml-task-to-run-an-xpath-query/).

Answer (score 1):

You're not distinguishing very clearly between the schema you are writing to describe and constrain your data (and, I assume, guide SSIS in various ways) and the executable code you will at some point want to write in order to extract the data you want at a particular moment.  There are several things you seem to want or need:

- To allow unconstrained XML within an element, you'll want a wildcard; read up on the `xsd:any` element.
- To extract just the text within an element, you'll want the XPath `string()` function (but note that your example `"this is a new piece of content by <b>Person A</b>"` is not just the text of `content` but contains a child element).
- To extract a serialized XML representation of the content of the `content` element (which is what you apparently want, in contrast to what you say you want), you'll want to serialize the contents; there are a variety of ways to do that.

Comment: If I have a 
"this is a new piece of content by <b>Person A</b>"
or 
"this is a new piece of content by <Person A"

I want to load both to a the same column as they are. 
Currently the tags and contained values are being ignored.
Is there a way to allow both cases in my mapping schema? Current schema entry is: ``<xs:element name="content" type="xs:string" sql:field = "storyContent" />`` Thanks.

Comment: I don't have the foggiest idea what you mean by "as they are".  It looks as if you may be thinking of XML elements as strings, which may or may not contain markup; XSD thinks of XML elements as nodes in a tree, which may or may not have children.  Are you assuming that `<content>this is a new piece of content by <b>Person A</b></content>` and `<content>this is a new piece of content by &lt;b>Person A&lt;/b></content>` are somehow the same?

Comment: if I encounter any tag within <content></content> I want to include it not filter it out as is currently happening.

Comment: There is no pattern to the tags included within <content>. I just want to take everything within those tags

Comment: I'll say this one more time. XSD does not see content with 'tags'. It sees content with child elements. If you want the b element in your example not to be a child element, then your XML input needs to stop lying by saying that it is.  If you don't want to or cannot change the format of your input, and you still want to store the entire content of `content` as a string, you need a transformation of the input, not just a mapping from input elements to your database's columns.